# .htaccess profile rewrite help

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

`RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*) profile.php?user=$1&v=$2 [L]` works for http://10.0.1.5/user/Kevin/wall/

if i do http://10.0.1.5/user/Kevin/wall it 404's.
if i do http://10.0.1.5/user/Kevin/ it 404's
if i do http://10.0.1.5/user/Kevin it 404's

I tired

```
 RewriteRule ^user/(.*) profile.php?user=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^user/(.*) profile.php?user=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)/ profile.php?user=$1&v=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*) profile.php?user=$1&v=$2 [L]
```

But it didn't work like i wanted. I want it to work with all 4 possible urls. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a more specific pattern than `.*` like `[^/]+` and use `/?$` to make the trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1&v=$2 [L]
```

But as I recommend to just use one of the formats (with or without trailing slash), remove or add the trailing slash if it is present or missing:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Does it really matter if the site has a mix of both?

Comment: @Keverw: No, you can use whatever URLs you want. But I would just use a consistent scheme.